# Definition of Domain and Region

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, analytic-geometry

First of all, I would like to ascertain the definition of domain vs region.

**Definition (Region)**
$\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ is a region if and only if its interior is nonempty.

**Definition (Bounded Region)**
$\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ is a bounded region if and only if it is a region and $\exists R>0, \, \Omega \subset B(0,R)$.

My question is how to show that
$\Omega = \mathbb{N}$ is not a region?

1 Do I have a correct definition of region?
2 Is the word "region" and "domain interchangable?
3 In the context of a domain for partial differential equation, do we say domain as "domain of a function" or a "region" instead?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Regarding 1 and 2, the words "region" and "domain" are two of the most over used, and ambiguously used, words in topology and geometry (not to speak of the rest of mathematics). If you are reading something, you must see exactly what that author means by those terms. If you are writing something, you must define exactly what you mean by those terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observe that for any natural point $n\in \mathbb{N}$ you have that for each $\epsilon>0$ then

$B(n,\epsilon) \cap \mathbb{N}^c\neq \emptyset$

So $n$ cannot be a internal point of $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Thank you, but before I jump into the proof, I want to ask whether my definition of region is correct in this context?

Also, how do we define internal point rigorously?

Comment: In the context of PDE or ODE the domain is the maximal domain of definition of the solution. Let X a topological space and A a subset of X. We say that x\in A is internal in A if there exists an open set U that contains x and is contained in A. You can observe that the set of internal point of A is an open set of X

Comment: @EvanWilliamChandra I guess you must have some source of the definitions. If so then  have a look there. Different sources may provide different definitions.